# why isn't the render function working?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-router, react-redux

I am trying to make a react app which fetches data from the Youtube Api . App is my main component and VideoList is a sub component. when i include the VideoList component into the render function for the App component the console shows me errors and the output is a blank page.according to me the output should be 5 because the length of videos array is 5 .i cant understand where i am making mistake.i am new to react any help would be appreciated . here is my code

App component

```
       class App extends Component {

       constructor(props)
       {
        super(props);

         this.state={ videos: [] };

          YTSearch({key:API_KEY, term:'surfboards'},(data) =>{
         this.setState({videos:data});
      } );

      }

      render()
       {
        return (
         <div>
          <SearchBar/>
           <VideoList videos={this.state.videos}/>
         </div>
        );
       }


        }
```

VideoList component

```
                const VideoList = (props) =>
                {
                 return 
                 (   <div>
                      <ul className="col-md-4 list-group">
                       {props.videos.length}
                       </ul>
                      </div>
                 );

                 }
```

Comment: the call to youtube data fetch should done inside the `componentDidMount` method. According to react docs "If you need to load data from a remote endpoint, this is a good place to instantiate the network request. "

Comment: the code looks ok, validate your youtube api call is returning data correctly

Comment: when i use console.log(data) inside the YTSearch function it shows an array of 5 objects which means the data is getting fetched .

Comment: i think there is some problem in the videolist component. the error pops up when i include this in my render.

Comment: what is the exact error you are getting

Comment: Warning: VideoList(...): No `render` method found on the returned component instance: you may have forgotten to define `render`, returned null/false from a stateless component, or tried to render an element whose type is a function that isn't a React component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, There is a issue in the way you written the component, you need to write it like this:

```
const VideoList = (props) => {
    return (   // ( should be in the same line
        <div>
            <ul className="col-md-4 list-group">
                {props.videos.length}
            </ul>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Because if you write like this:

```
return
(
.....
```

It will not `return` anything and will be treated as **return;**

**Suggestion:** Instead of fetching the data in `constructor`, do the api call in `componentDidMount` lifecycle, like this:

```
componentDidMount(){
     YTSearch({key:API_KEY, term:'surfboards'},
         (data) => {
            this.setState({videos:data});
         }
     )
}
```

Comment: thanks a ton sir it worked !!..i wonder why it doesnt return anything when i place it a new line?

Comment: because it will be treated as `return;`